# How to calculate the variance of specific variable across multiple datasets in R

Tags: r, variance

I have 3 data sets, each with variables `time_tick`, `gyr_X_value`, `gyr_Y_value`, and `gyr_Z_value`.

An example of one of the data sets is as follows:

```
 time_tick gyr_X_value  gyr_Y_value  gyr_Z_value
1   .01    .12             .24         -.28               
2   .12      0               0          .05
3   .04    .10               0          .17
4   .03      0            -.25          .15
```

I know that I can calculate the variance of the each individual data set with `var()`, but how can I calculate the variance of `gyr_X_value` across all three data sets?

Comment: When you say *data sets* I can only assume you mean a *data frame*... You need to elaborate on your question and show what you have tried so far and where you are actually stuck. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) question to help you write a minimal reproducible example (or *reprex*) will help you get a more positive response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can place the datasets in a `list`, extract the 'gyr_X_value' column, and use the `rowVars` if we need to find the variance of each row

```
library(matrixStats)
rowVars(sapply(list(df1, df2, df3), `[[`, 'gyr_X_value'))
```

Suppose, the interest is to find variance of the specific column for each dataset, then use `var` after extracting the column

```
sapply(list(df1, df2, df3), function(x) var(x[['gyr_X_value']]))
```

Note: The object names are assumed as 'df1', 'df2', 'df3'

Answer (score 0):

You can use rbind.  Given data frames a, b, and c, they can be combined by row with

```
combined <- rbind(a,b,c)
```

[See here for detailed usage.](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/library/base/html/cbind.html).  Then you can use var() as usual on a given column, for example, combined[, 2].

Answer (score 0):

For those kinds of problems, I strongly recommend the tidyverse approach.

Your data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "time_tick gyr_X_value  gyr_Y_value  gyr_Z_value
1   .01    .12             .24         -.28               
2   .12      0               0          .05
3   .04    .10               0          .17
4   .03      0            -.25          .15", header = TRUE)
```

The calculation:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% gather(variable, value, -time_tick) %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  summarize(variance = var(value))

## A tibble: 3 x 2
#     variable variance
#        <chr>    <dbl>
#1 gyr_X_value 0.004100
#2 gyr_Y_value 0.040025
#3 gyr_Z_value 0.043425
```

Explanation: First, the gather function turns your wide data frame into a long one:

```
df %>% gather(variable, value, -time_tick)
#   time_tick    variable value
#1       0.01 gyr_X_value  0.12
#2       0.12 gyr_X_value  0.00
#3       0.04 gyr_X_value  0.10
#4       0.03 gyr_X_value  0.00
#5       0.01 gyr_Y_value  0.24
#6       0.12 gyr_Y_value  0.00
#7       0.04 gyr_Y_value  0.00
#8       0.03 gyr_Y_value -0.25
#9       0.01 gyr_Z_value -0.28
#10      0.12 gyr_Z_value  0.05
#11      0.04 gyr_Z_value  0.17
#12      0.03 gyr_Z_value  0.15
```

The `group_by()` function then sets up the grouping by `variable`, and the `summarize()` function calculates the variance separately within the groupings.